# Is it always okay to put "now" in a sentence when the tense is present perfect?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Is it always okay to put "now" in a sentence For any context or with any verb when the tense is present perfect?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean *always* okay? Even if you give an example where it's fine (and you should give at least one example so that your question is clear), that doesn't mean that it will be fine in *every* sentence. There are so many exceptions to everything that it's pretty much impossible to say *always* or *never* when it comes to English.

Comment: @JasonBassford I could give you any sentences from every different sources... but I asked it because I thought I finally found some kind of magic word to give me a standard when to use present perfect tense or past tense. Generally, you'd be instantly wrong if you put 'now' in a past tense sentence, right? I was wondering if you just put 'now' in every present perfect sentence regardless of the changes in meaning. Well, at least you'd be not wrong grammatically, right? (-> this is what I was wondering actually) Could you give me some magic word other than "now"? Would "currently" work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often add "now" but it isn't meaningless.

> I have finished breakfast

That is a simple statement of fact

> I have now finished breakfast

Is a conversational strategy, it suggests a context in which "now" is significant. Perhaps this is the second time you asked me about breakfast, the first time I hadn't finished, but "now" I have.  The word "now" must be emphasising something, but exactly what you are emphasising needs to be part of the context.

Note the position of "now". It can be in other places in the sentence, but just before the main verb sounds better to me.

Comment: Thank you!! Then, if you ignore the slight changes in meanings, can you still put "now" in any present perfect tense sentence without causing any grammar mistake? In other words, when you put "now" in any past tense sentence, it'd be instantly bad regardless of the meaning itself. But it seems like there is not a single grammar issue when it comes to 'present perfect tense'.

Comment: Grammatically correct?  Probably.  But there are probably plenty of situations where "now" would be odd.  Perhaps you could give an example of the sort of thing you are thinking about.